# How to know updated available heap size?

Tags: android, memory-management, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I am facing difficulties to get updated available heap size of application after removing some of the large objects.

My requirement is to free the memory once user reach the specific level of heap size. e.g I am using Samsung Tab3 which has 64 Mb heap size for an application.

Application should't go out of memory while viewing images, hence i have restricted 55 MB as max limit for heap size to grow. I am checking available heap size before view image. If the heap size is greater than 55 MB then I remove the some of the images which are recently viewed, so i can get enough memory to load image.

But the problem is that the, after removing images objects, I got the last increased heap size, which is always greater than 55 MB. I also called gc after remove each image, but doesn't affect.

I want the decreased heap size after removing image object.

if heap has reached 55 MB then on each removal heap should decrease, how to get decreased heap size?

I am using following codes to get available heap size.

```
/**
     * This method is used to get currently allocated heap size to application.
     */
    public static int getAllocatedHeapSize()
    {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
        int size = new Double(Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()/1048576).intValue();
        Log.d("heap", "debug.memory: allocated: " + size + "MB of " + df.format(new Double(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/1048576))+ "MB (" + df.format(new Double(Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()/1048576)) +"MB free)");
        return size;
    }

/**
     * Check whether free memory is available to store new attachment page
     * @return true if available else false
     */
    public static boolean isFreeMemoryAvailable()
    {
        int allocatedHeapSize = getAllocatedHeapSize();
        if (allocatedHeapSize > ) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

isFreeMemoryAvailable() method goes in infinite because its not getting updated heap size.

Give me a solution as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

`Runtime.totalMemory()` is not related to how much of the heap that is actually used when called. It returns the actual size of the heap. From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html#totalMemory()):

> Returns the number of bytes taken by the heap at its current size.

Removing objects does not necessarily change the heap size.

You could get the actual usage of the heap by doing:

```
Runtime.totalMemory() - Runtime.freeMemory();
```

That said, maybe you should look at storing your images in a `android.util.LruCache` or something instead of doing this management yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There are several aspects to this question:

1) You might get more reliable and detailed statistics using java management beans, e.g., http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryMXBean.html among other (MemoryMXBean, MemoryPoolMXBean, GarbageCollectorMXBean)

2) You cannot reduce your heap size from within the java application, you can only reduce your usage of the heap.

3) You might consider the usage of Soft References http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html. This class enables you to keep references as long as the space is not needed otherwise, and collect it only when absolutely necessary. This way you can limit your heap size, and use soft references to keep data as long as possible but do not impede the GC collecting it if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this is a android question.

Comment: Yes, but my answer is still valid, even for android.